# Button with image in: suppress the flicked effect when it's clicked

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I have defined a button with a image in it (in a wp7 app). I want to be able to click it, but I don't want it to flicker when it's clicked. Is it possible?

```
<Button Name="imageButton" BorderThickness="0" Height="80" Width="80" Margin="0,-10,0,0" Clip="">
    <Image Source="{Binding favoriteIcon}" Width="35" Height="35" Stretch="Uniform"/>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the 'flicker' effect I presume you mean the way that the colour of the button becomes inverted when clicked?

This behaviour is defined in the Button template, sorry for the huge block of code, but here it is with the part that causes this effect highlighted:

```
<Style x:Key="PhoneButtonBase" TargetType="ButtonBase">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
  <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
  <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>
  <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,3,10,5"/>

  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ButtonBase">
        <Grid Background="Transparent">
          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
              <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>

              <!-- the following visual state describes the behaviour you are observing -->
              <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" >
            <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
          </Border>
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

You can create a copy of this template and removed the 'Pressed' state effects to remove it.

Comment: Yes, about the inverted color I was talking. thanks for helping!